# Update Successfully but Data not update in db. Django rest framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer, pgadmin-4

I'm working on my final year project, and I need some help to understand what is actually happening, **The problem is that**: I hit the Update request through postman which gives the successful message for updating the data. but when I check my Database there is no updated data. I also did the debugging but there was no exception by which I can understand the problem Anyone can please help me?
I'm using

**PgAdmin** for my database.

**Django==4.0.2**

**djangorestframework==3.13.1**

**djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0**

**djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.0.0**

**psycopg2==2.9.3****.

**My Models:**

```
class Company(Base):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='Company_Name')
    company_email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255, db_column='company_email')
    company_manager_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='Manager_Name')
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='Company_address')
    about_company = models.TextField()
    company_website = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column='IsActive', help_text='I will use this for enable/disable '
                                                                                  'a specific record')

    class Meta:
        db_table: 'Company'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if not self.pk:
                self.company_email = self.company_email.replace(" ", "").lower()
                super().save()
        except Exception:
            raise
```

```
class Base(models.Model):
    """Following fields are abstract and will be use in All over the project Any time Anywhere"""
    create_by = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='CreatedBy', null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    create_on = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CreatedOn', auto_now_add=True)
    modified_by = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ModifiedBy', null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(db_column='ModifiedOn', auto_now=True)
    deleted_by = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='DeletedBy', null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    deleted_on = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DeletedOn', auto_now=True)
    status = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='Status', default=0, help_text='I will use this field for making'
                                                                             'the status like pending approved and '
                                                                             'for some other purpose by Default it is '
                                                                             'Zero which has no meaning', )

    class Meta:
        abstract: True
```

**serializer.py:**

```
class CompanyUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_null=False, allow_blank=False)
    company_email = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_null=False, allow_blank=False)
    company_manager_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_null=False, allow_blank=False)
    company_address = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_null=False, allow_blank=False)
    about_company = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_null=False, allow_blank=False)
    company_website = serializers.URLField(allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['id', 'company_name', 'company_email', 'company_manager_name', 'company_address', 'about_company',
                  'company_website']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        try:
            instance.company_name = validated_data.get('company_name', instance.company_name)
            instance.company_email = validated_data.get('company_email', instance.company_email)
            instance.company_manager_name = validated_data.get('company_manager_name', instance.company_manager_name)
            instance.company_address = validated_data.get('company_address', instance.company_address)
            instance.about_company = validated_data.get('about_company', instance.about_company)
            instance.company_website = validated_data.get('company_website', instance.company_website)
            instance.save()

            return instance
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

**Views.py**

```
    def put(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            id1 = pk
            saved_company = Company.objects.get(pk=id1)
            data = request.data
            serializer = CompanyUpdateSerializer(instance=saved_company, data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return self.send_response(success=True, code=f'200', status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                                          description='Company is updated')
            return self.send_response(code=f'422', status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                                      description=serializer.errors)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return self.send_response(code='422', status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                                      description="No Company matches the given query.")
        except IntegrityError:
            return self.send_response(code=f'422', status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                                      description="Email Already Exist")
        except Company.DoesNotExist:
            return self.send_response(code=f'422', status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                                      description="Company Model doesn't exists")
        except FieldError:
            return self.send_response(code=f'500', description="Cannot resolve keyword given in 'order_by' into field")
        except Exception as e:
            return self.send_response(code=f'500', description=e)
```

Comment: Your put method doesn't look correct, it is more of a post method. Will write the code tomorrow morning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from `Company.save()` method.

You overrode it as

```py
class Company(Base):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if not self.pk:
                self.company_email = self.company_email.replace(" ", "").lower()
                super().save()
        except Exception:
            raise
```

Notice the call of `super().save()` inside the `self.pk` is `None` if statement block.

This will make the actual save method to be called only when the `pk` is `None`, meaning that only when a new instance is created, not when an instance is updated.

Moving the `super().save()` call to be outside the if statement should handle both creating and updating.

```py
class Company(Base):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if not self.pk:
                self.company_email = self.company_email.replace(" ", "").lower()
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            raise
```